# How to translate "spirit brands"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How can we say in German "Cocktails with local spirit brands"?

I am facing difficulties to translate the part "spirit brands".

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 12):

English "brand" corresponds to German "Marke", but a literal translation of "brand" by "Marke" often yields unidiomatic results. The word is less ubiquitous in German than in English. I'd suggest to drop it completely. For "local", I'd prefer "heimisch" to "örtlich" or "lokal" in this context. So the result is

> Cocktails mit heimischen Spirituosen

Answer (score 2):

In this case it may work better to not use a too verbatim translation. Both *local*, and *spirit brands* are not what comes into mind first. A natural way to say this is is e.g.:

> Cocktails mit Spirituosen aus der Umgebung.

If we need to be closer to the original another suggestion would be:

> Cocktails aus Bränden regionaler Brennereien.

Note that in German *local* in this context is translated with *regional* or as was already said, *heimisch*.

Answer (score 0):

Spirits are **Spirituosen** in German and brands are **Marken**.

So your sentence, assuming you mean

> Cocktails with local[ly made] spirit brands

would be

> Cocktails (sic!), die mit örtlichen/lokalen Spirituosenmarken gemacht
>   wurden

or

> Cocktails mit Sprituosenmarken aus der örtlichen Umgebung.

The last one would be literally translated back into English as

> Cocktails with spirit brands from the local surroundings.

The word cocktails has long been borrowed into the German language.

Comment: On a menu, you would probably find it shorter: "Cocktails *aus* lokalen Spirituosen"

Comment: Wohl wahr, wollte aber Speisekartenkurzform vermeiden. ;)

Comment: @toro: Da Cocktails selten nur Spirituosen enthalten wohl eher "mit lokalen S."

Comment: "Gemacht" als generisches Verb würde ich durch "gemixt" o.ä. ersetzen - passt aber nicht zur Frage, die auch kein Verb hat. Satz 3: "C mit SM der örtlichen Umgebung" (ohne "aus") genügt auch.

Comment: @userunknown Die meisten Speise-/Getränkekarten, die ich bisher gesehen habe, waren da nicht so unvorsichtig wie du... *mit* könnte nämlich auch mißverstanden werden als "ich erwarte, da stellt mir einer einen Cocktail hin und ein paar lokale Spirituosen dazu"

Comment: Meine Vorsicht ist eher aus Unerfahrenheit: was ist denn bevorzugt? "Korrektes" vollständiges deutsch, oder auch umgangssprachlich, einschliesslich Kurzformen, wie man sie auf z.B. einer Speisekarte finden würde? Wobei ich spezifische Anfragen nach Umgangssprache ausschliesse.

Comment: @tofro Das was Du meinst, nennt sich im Speisekartendeutschen "Cocktail *an* lokalen Spirituosen".

Comment: @Uwe Nein. "*an*" heisst: "Wir mussten die Sachen *nebeneinander* legen, damit der Teller wenigstens ein bißchen voll wird"